# ObservableCollection<object>

Tags: avalonia

имею такое

```
public object[]? obj;
public ObservableCollection<object>datatablew { get; set; }
public diztablew(object grps)
{
    datatablew = new ObservableCollection<object>() { grps };
    obj = new object[3];
    obj[0] = "1111";
    datatablew.Add(obj);
}
```

DataGrid правильно размечает столбики из grps , но не видит значения ("1111") , вроде есть
уже подобная тема но там обьяснения не для начинающего . Поможите пожалуйста .

Часть проблемы я решил так

````
public void init(object grps, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conns)
        {
            var testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(grps.GetType().Assembly.FullName?.Split(",")[0] + ".dll");
            var t = testAssembly.GetType(grps.GetType().FullName);
            datatablew = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            string cluc = "select top 10 kod_rel,uet,rtrim(name) as name from statistika.dbo.statpra";
            var comms = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(cluc, conns);
            var readers = comms.ExecuteReader();
            var counts = readers.FieldCount;
            object statpra = new build.statpra();
            while (readers.Read() == true)
            {
                obj = new object[counts];
                var ooo = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                readers.GetValues(obj);
                var ps = ooo.GetType().GetProperties();
                for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
                {
                    var obbjj = readers.GetValue(i);
                    try
                    {
                        var pps = grps.GetType().GetProperty(readers.GetName(i));
                        pps.SetValue(ooo,obbjj,null); 
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                datatablew.Add(ooo);
            }
            readers.Close();
        }
`осталось решить это` 
<DataGridTextColumn CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="kod_rel" Binding="{Binding ????,StringFormat=0;-0;#}"/>
`, как забиндить kod_rel который есть в ObservableCollection<object> , если я ставлю ```AutoGenerateColumns="true"``` 
то все работает как надо но мне надо колонки определять самому .`
````

Comment: Все отлично получилось , я что-то тормознул создавая столбики в дизайнере и получая ошибку , столбики создаются программно и после того как  ObservableCollection уже заполнен , тогда ни каких ошибок нет . При таком подходе можно создать универсальную таблицу что значительно сокращает программный код .